# How to pass data to Servlet from Jquery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

Am trying to send some a value i.e. fileShareName to Servlet through this code but am unable to send it .Please guide me ..
Here is am having the code :

```
function shareFileName(){
    var fileShareName = $('#newpathlocation').find(":selected").text();
    row = "";
    $
            .ajax({
                url : '../directory',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {'fileName' : fileShareName},
                datatype : String,
                beforeSend: function( fileShareName ){},
                success : function(fileShareName) {
                        alert("Success");
                    },
                error : function(fileShareName) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Is a request being sent? What does `datatype:String` do ?

Comment: every time the request is going to the error part ...

Comment: is there an error message? Look at the developer console.

Comment: Thanks for the response got the alternate solution for it.